# R gSignalConnect

Tags: r

I'm trying to learn how to signalConnect buttons to labels. For example, I've made a button labeled "+" and created a label initialized to "0". I would like the button to adjust the label by adding one every time the button is clicked. I have constructed the button and the window for it. My question is, how do I use the `gSignalConnect()` function to perform this?

Thanks,

Joe

-- Here is my code

```
win <- gtkWindow(show = FALSE)

win$Resize( width = 700, height = 500)

win$SetTitle(title = "Measurement GUI")

frame <- gtkFixedNew()

win$add(frame)

plus<-gtkButtonNewWithLabel("+")

plus$setSizeRequest(80,35)

frame$put(plus, 10, 50)

label <-gtkLabelNew("0")

frame$put(label, 100, 80)

win$ShowAll()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
callback <- function(btn, ...) {
  old <- as.numeric(label$getText())
  label$setText(old + 1)
}

gSignalConnect(plus, "clicked", callback)
```

To use `gSignalConnect`, you will need to know which signals (and their signatures) are available for your widget. `?gtkButton` will give this information.